# SwiftUI: Custom binding that get value from @StateObject property is set back to old value after StateObject property change

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to implement a passcode view in iOS. I was following the guide [here](https://imthath.medium.com/swiftui-passcode-field-for-otp-and-pin-entry-b61ba663dc31).

I'm trying to improve it a bit so it allows me to create a passcode by enter same passcode twice. I added a "state" property to the @StateObject and want to clear entered passcode after user input the passcode first time.

Here is my current code:

```
LockScreenModel.swift
====================
import Foundation

class LockScreenModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var pin: String = ""
    @Published var showPin = false
    @Published var isDisabled = false
    @Published var state = LockScreenState.normal
}

enum LockScreenState: String, CaseIterable {
    case new
    case verify
    case normal
    case remove
}
====================

LockScreen.swift
====================
import SwiftUI

struct LockScreen: View {
    
    @StateObject var lockScreenModel = LockScreenModel()
    
    let initialState: LockScreenState
    var handler: (String, LockScreenState, (Bool) -> Void) -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            Text(NSLocalizedString("lock.label.\(lockScreenModel.state.rawValue)", comment: "")).font(.title)
            ZStack {
                pinDots
                backgroundField
            }
            showPinStack
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {lockScreenModel.state = initialState})
        .onDisappear(perform: {
            lockScreenModel.pin = ""
            lockScreenModel.showPin = false
            lockScreenModel.isDisabled = false
            lockScreenModel.state = .normal
        })
    }

    private var pinDots: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            ForEach(0..<6) { index in
                Image(systemName: self.getImageName(at: index))
                    .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .thin, design: .default))
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    private var backgroundField: some View {
        let boundPin = Binding<String>(get: { lockScreenModel.pin }, set: { newValue in
            if newValue.last?.isWholeNumber == true {
                lockScreenModel.pin = newValue
            }
            self.submitPin()
        })
        
        return TextField("", text: boundPin, onCommit: submitPin)
            .accentColor(.clear)
            .foregroundColor(.clear)
            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            .disabled(lockScreenModel.isDisabled)
    }
    
    private var showPinStack: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            if !lockScreenModel.pin.isEmpty {
                showPinButton
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 20)
        .padding([.trailing])
    }
    
    private var showPinButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            lockScreenModel.showPin.toggle()
        }, label: {
            lockScreenModel.showPin ?
            Image(systemName: "eye.slash.fill").foregroundColor(.primary) :
            Image(systemName: "eye.fill").foregroundColor(.primary)
        })
    }
    
    private func submitPin() {
        guard !lockScreenModel.pin.isEmpty else {
            lockScreenModel.showPin = false
            return
        }
        
        if lockScreenModel.pin.count == 6 {
            lockScreenModel.isDisabled = true
            handler(lockScreenModel.pin, lockScreenModel.state) { isSuccess in
                if isSuccess && lockScreenModel.state == .new {
                    lockScreenModel.state = .verify
                    lockScreenModel.pin = ""
                    lockScreenModel.isDisabled = false
                } else if !isSuccess {
                    lockScreenModel.pin = ""
                    lockScreenModel.isDisabled = false
                    print("this has to called after showing toast why is the failure")
                }
            }
        }
        
        // this code is never reached under  normal circumstances. If the user pastes a text with count higher than the
        // max digits, we remove the additional characters and make a recursive call.
        if lockScreenModel.pin.count > 6 {
            lockScreenModel.pin = String(lockScreenModel.pin.prefix(6))
            submitPin()
        }
    }
    
    private func getImageName(at index: Int) -> String {
        if index >= lockScreenModel.pin.count {
            return "circle"
        }
        
        if lockScreenModel.showPin {
            return lockScreenModel.pin.digits[index].numberString + ".circle"
        }
        
        return "circle.fill"
    }
}

extension String {
    var digits: [Int] {
        var result = [Int]()
        for char in self {
            if let number = Int(String(char)) {
                result.append(number)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}

extension Int {
    var numberString: String {
        guard self < 10 else { return "0" }
        return String(self)
    }
}
====================
```

The problem is the line `lockScreenModel.state = .verify`. If I include this line, the passcode TextField won't get cleared, but if I remove this line, the passcode TextField is cleared.

If I add a breakpoint in `set` method of `boundPin`, I can see after set `pin` to empty and `state` to `verify`, the `set` method of `boundPin` is called with `newValue` of the old `pin` which I have no idea why. If I only set `pin` to empty but don't set `state` to `verify`, that `set` method of `boundPin` won't get called which confuse me even more. I can't figure out which caused this strange behavior.

Comment: Does the code compile? `initialState` is not initialized and what does `handler`? Unrelated but if `lockScreenModel` occurs more than twice in a view function, the function is supposed to be moved from the view to `lockScreenModel`.

Comment: It can compile, you can use it with something like

```
LockScreen(initialState: LockScreenState.new) { passcode, state, act in
            print(passcode)
            act(false)
}
```

I tried to put multiple assignment inside lockScreenModel and call that function instead. Same result.